# Gráfico de barras ordenado utilizando dplyr e ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Eu gostaria de criar um gráfico de barras após contar o número de ocorrências das categorias de um conjunto de dados. Suponha que meu conjunto de dados é este abaixo:

```
dados <- structure(list(categorias = structure(c(5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor")), .Names = "categorias", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Eu consigo contar o número de ocorrências de cada categoria e fazer o gráfico de barras correspondente desta maneira:

```
dados %>%
  group_by(categorias) %>%
  count() %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=categorias, y=n)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto, as barras estão colocadas em ordem alfabética. Eu gostaria que estivessem colocadas da mais frequente para a menos frequente. No caso deste exemplo, elas deveriam estar na ordem A, E, C, D, B.

Eu não gostaria de soluções utilizando algo na linha de

```
ggplot(dados, aes(x=categorias)) +
  geom_bar(stat="count")
```

pois acho que meu código fica mais organizado da outra maneira.

Há alguma maneira de fazer o que desejo utilizando o primeiro código que coloquei acima?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tive uma ideia de como pesquisar minha dúvida e acabei chegando a uma resposta poucos instantes depois de publicar minha pergunta:

```
dados %>%
  group_by(categorias) %>%
  count() %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=reorder(categorias, -n), y=n)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta solução fica elegante.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no pacote [forcats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forcats/index.html). Ele foi construído pelo Hadley para facilitar manipulações de factors, visando visualização via ggplot2.