# Reordenar as colunas de um gráfico de barras e da sua legenda

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Ao processar e plotar dados no R utilizando o tidyverse, ele por padrão deixa a ordem das barras do gráfico na ordem original dos fatores da coluna:

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg$trans <- as.factor(mpg$trans)

mpg %>%
  group_by(trans) %>%
  count(trans) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = trans, y = n, fill = trans)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que as barras aparecessem ordenadas pela sua frequência. [Eu já havia feito uma pergunta similar por aqui, mas na época eu não havia considerado o caso com legenda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216305/gr%C3%A1fico-de-barras-ordenado-utilizando-dplyr-e-ggplot2). Por isso, ao utilizar a solução desta pergunta, eu fico com o resultado abaixo:

```
mpg %>%
  group_by(trans) %>%
  count(trans) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = reorder(trans, n), y = n, fill = trans)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note o uso da função `reorder` dentro da função `ggplot` para deixar as barras na ordem que desejo. Entretanto, a ordem dos itens na legenda `trans` continua na ordem original dos níveis do fator.

O que eu gostaria: que as barras ficassem em uma ordem idêntica à que aparece no gráfico anterior, com a legenda nesta mesma ordem. No CMR acima, a ordem da legenda deveria ser

- auto(l3)
- auto(s4)
- auto(s5)
  ...
- manual(m5)
- auto(l4)

Como posso fazer isto de maneira automatizada? Isto é, sem precisar definir os níveis do fator `trans` manualmente?

Desconsidere a legenda do eixo x sobreposta. Acabei não consertando isso em meu exemplo, mas a versão final do gráfico terá este problema resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode puxar o `reorder` pra um `mutate`, aí já ajeita as barras e as legendas de uma vez só.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>%
  group_by(trans) %>%
  count(trans) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(trans = reorder(trans, n)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = trans, y = n, fill = trans)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Uma solução tão óbvia e eu não tinha me ligado nela.